# Printerdriver Windows XP for HP OfficeJet T65

Tags: drivers, printer

Where can I find a printerdriver (Windows XP) for a HP OfficeJet T65? Cannot find at the HP support site and we've lost the original cd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is official HP site with driver for XP http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&product=58125

I never find anything on HP, Dell or any other sites. I prefer to search Google and use advance options to search specific site.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=uk&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=58125#N159) is the driver you need for your HP Officejet t65 All-in-One Printer. To help you next time, I Googled: HP OfficeJet T65.